# zend _forward in controller plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a controller plugin that is detecting if the site has been set to maintenance, if it has, i want it to _forward to the maintenance controller to display the 'sorry...' message.

I don't want to use a redirect as this will change the current url the user is on, but _forward is a Zend_Controller_Action protected method so can't be called out of context, how do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the `preDispatch` method of your plugin is called, the request isn't dispatched. So you can "forward" just by setting the controller and action on the request:

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    if ($this->isMaintenanceMode()) {
        $request->setControllerName('error');
        $request->setActionName('maintenance');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the plugin cannot _forward() properly; In your controller(s) `init()` method you can check for a flag that says your site is in maintenance mode *AND* the action isn't your maintenance action then `$this->_forward('maintenance-action');`

Something like:

```
// .. in your action controller
public function init() {
    $maintenanceMode = checkTheFlagYourPluginSet();
    // .. other code removed omitted
    if ($maintainenceMode && $this->_request->getActionName() != 'maintenance-action') {
        // return so that nothing else gets executed in the init()
        return $this->_forward('maintenance-action');
    }
}
```